# How to extend html template with jquery content by jinja2?

Tags: python, html, jquery, flask

Here is my html code

**Base.html**

```
<title> {% block title %}{% endblock %} </title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            
            
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/content">Home</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calendar</a>
        
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Still in progress...</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

and then this is my jquery code:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
<title>Datepicker</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>



<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
 });
</script>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Schedule an Appointment</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="/ok" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Appointment Time</label>
                            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" name="Time"/>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I have tried many times to modify the index.html to be able to extent by the base.html but failed.
Neither only the background color change nor the jquery cannot be load in the chrome, as a result no datetimepicker is appear.
How can I use the {% extends "base.html" %} (jinja2 method) to extend the base.html to index.html?
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to define

`{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

in base.html and then in the index.html.

`{% extends "base.html" %} // at top of file`

All the content should be between

`{% block content %}{% endblock %}` in index.html. you can see in [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/templateinheritance/)

Answer (score 0):

base.html

```
<html> ...
```

your_main_html.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
<style>
     <!-- your css codes -->
</style>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<!-- your html and jinja codes -->
{% endblock %}

{% block extrajs %}
 <script>
    <!-- your js codes -->
 </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still not work, only the base template is shown but the calendar picker is still missing

Comment: If you check your template path you can handle all of that i think. I think you may be getting path error while rendering the template

Answer (score 0):

you will need to download jQuery js file from https://jquery.com/download/ and use it in your index file inside head tag as 
`<script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>`
or
use jQuery CDN as below
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`